# Custom made bot check

Tags: php

I have problem with my contact form. I have four fields, name, email, message and one field where you enter characters to confirm you are not robot.
I generate 4 random characters from array (arrays is made of A-Z, a-z and 0-9) and someone who use contact form needs to enter that chars to confirm he is not bot. My code is still raw cause i am working on it, it is not organized, seperated in different .php file and functions. Problem is after i click on submit button new chars generate and when comparing entered and generated chars they never match (somehow submit refresh page and php code runs again and generate different chars). My guess is cause contact form sending values to itself (same page) and that refreshes page (run again php code)

```
            <?php
            $nameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = ''; 
            $niz1 = range ('A', 'Z');
            $niz2 = range ('a', 'z');
            $niz3 = range ('0', '9');
            $niz = array_merge($niz1, $niz3, $niz2);
            $provera = "";
            for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
                $j=rand(0, 61);
                $provera .= $niz[$j]; 
            }
            $array[] = $provera;
            if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email= $_POST['email'];
                $message= $_POST['message'];
                $robot = $_POST['robot'];
                $formcontent= "From: $name \n Message: \n $message";
                $recipient= "someemail@gmail.com";
                $subject= "Contact Form";
                $mailheader= "From: $email \r\n";

                if(strlen($name)==0) {
                    $nameErr = " Name is required";
                }
                elseif(strlen($email)==0) {
                    $emailErr = " Email is required";
                }
                elseif(strlen($message)==0) {
                    $messageErr = " Message is required";
                }
                else {

                    if ($robot == $provera) {
                        $confirmation = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
                        if ($confirmation == true) {
                            echo "$name, thank you for submitting message";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "For some reason message could not be sent, please use some other way to contact me";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print_r ($array); // this is only to check what i have
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo $robot;
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

I have tried with $array to store generated chars in array so if hitting submit somehow runs my php code again it will be store in $array[1] and old chars in $array[0] so i can use that or prev($array) to compare entered chars with chars on previous position in my array, but with clicking submit $array is also reseted from start and values are stored in $array[0].. Maybe i can solve this by sending values from contact form to another page and not to same page where it is or by using session_start, i am stucked but at least tell me if i am thinking in the right direction or i am totally wrong

Comment: The generation of the unique code will run every time the page is called.  Due to the randomness of the generation, it's highly unlikely you'll get two codes the same one after the other.  Have a look into PHP sessions, store the code in the session and compare when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks, i already asked if sessions is good way to solve this problem i am having. I tried to solve it with array, so i store generated code in array (array[0], array[1] ...) but arrays is alwasy reseted to array[0] position which i checked with print_r in my code. I guess when i hit submit since it sends values to same page where php code is page is refreshed and so is my array refreshed.. Sessions is the way to go, thx man..